# Word mail merge using excel column to select layout from other documents

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have about 30 word documents.

There is 1 document that is the main one setup to use for mail merge.

There is a column in the recipiant list that is meant to select the document that will be used for that row. so for example there is a column that looks like:

```
TY_LETTER_NO
02F
41E
02E
```

and there are word documents with file names

```
r02F.doc
r41E.doc
r02E.doc
```

The main document was corrupted I believe and when trying to do the mail merge as usual we were receiving an error. "a field calculation error occurred in record #"

So from what I read the document was corrupted.

I remade the document and the mail merge as I know how. but I don't know how to use the excel column to select the other document templates.

I am still able to open the original master mail merge document but I don't see anywhere that indicates this either.

Comment: It is hard to help you. Can you provide some more background for instance the macro being used?

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't see any macros in the word document. If I click developer>macros there is nothing listed in there

Comment: ok. It seems you will have to either develop it again, do it manually, restore from backup or something else. You may want to consider using the free vresion of Invantive Composition, but it is still somewhat different (i am involved with it). Good luck.